# How to Set up Environment Variables in "launch.json" Configuration When Using GDB Integration in VS Code

Tags: gdb, visual-studio-code

I have a setup in `launch.json` for vscode as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch 25.0_regeragpu",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/25.0_regeragpu/Blazer/MercuryImageComputer/KT/leaf/M31/BrightField/bin/LeafStandalone/Debug/12/LeafStandAlone.x86-64",
            "args": ["-noForcedPatches","${workspaceFolder}/virgo_algo_preq/JobDump/JobInfo_108"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/25.0_regeragpu/Blazer/MercuryImageComputer/KT/leaf/M31/BrightField/bin/LeafStandalone/Debug/12",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The purpose of this setup is to use GDB integration in vscode. In particular, I specified the following pair to ensure all environment variables set up in my bash session in terminal of vscode are inherited when debugging: `"externalConsole": false`. I also notice that there is a pair named `environment` in the configuration. It is my understanding that if a new bash session is started for debugging by vscode, then all environment variables should be specified in this `environment` pair. To try the option of starting a new bash when debug, I modified the configuration file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch 25.0_regeragpu",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/25.0_regeragpu/Blazer/MercuryImageComputer/KT/leaf/M31/BrightField/bin/LeafStandalone/Debug/12/LeafStandAlone.x86-64",
            "args": ["-noForcedPatches","${workspaceFolder}/virgo_algo_preq/JobDump/JobInfo_108"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/25.0_regeragpu/Blazer/MercuryImageComputer/KT/leaf/M31/BrightField/bin/LeafStandalone/Debug/12",
            "environment": [{"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":"0,1,2,3","CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER":"PCI_BUS_ID"}],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In particular, it can be seen that I specified the following pairs: `"environment": [{"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES":"0,1,2,3","CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER":"PCI_BUS_ID"}]` and `"externalConsole": true`. Nevertheless, as I started debugging, the debugging tool of vscode prepared forever and never entered the real debugging session. How should I set up the environment variables if I want to debug in a new console in vscode?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example, you set the value in the **environment** block.

```
    {
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++ - (GDB 9.2) Build and debug active file with RepoCodeInspection",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/bin/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [
            {
                "description": "same as commands below by using 'setenv ...",
                "info": "cant debug b/c of libBase/libRecipe now requiring dependency to boost for stacktrace dumps",
                "name": "LD_LIBRARY_PATH",
                "value": "/libs/:./"
            }
        ],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "logging": {
            "trace": false,
            "traceResponse": false
        },
        "preLaunchTask": "RepoCodeInspection",
        
    },
    {
        "name": "g++ - (GDB 9.2) Attach to a running process",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId":"${command:pickProcess}",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/bin/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "logging": {
            "trace": false,
            "traceResponse": false
        },
        "preLaunchTask": "RepoCodeInspection",
       
    },
]
```

}

Comment: The OP is already trying to use an `environment` block.  It would be better if you could *explain* your answer in English, rather than just hiding it in an unnecessarily-long code block.

Answer (score 3):

To set multiple environment variables, use comma-separated `"name"`, `"value"` pairs.

Example:

```
"environment": [{"name": "LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "value": "/ld/library/path/"},
                {"name": "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "value": "0"}
               ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's debug your problem.  First up, remember: this is a JSON file, thus we need to *think* of it as a JSON file.

This is your initial JSON object that we're thinking about:

```json
  "environment": [
    {
      "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES": "0,1,2,3",
      "CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER": "PCI_BUS_ID"
    }
  ]
```

So we have a JSON array (indicated by `[` & `]`) named "environment" which contains *a single object* (indicated by `{` & `}`).  That *single* object then contains *two* key/value pairs.  Here lies the problem.

A single object with multiple key value pairs is like a [`struct`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)) in C as opposed to a simple variable which has a *single* key/value pair.

Logically I would say what we *desire* is this:

- our "environment" would hold a number of "environement variables"
- our environment variables each have single key with a value.

Re-tooling our combination of `[]` & `{}` results in the following:

```json
  "environment": [
    {
      "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES": "0,1,2,3"
    },
    {
      "CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER": "PCI_BUS_ID"
    }
  ]
```